# Resizing a background-image using pure css inside a class:hover

Tags: html, css, hover, scale

I have a image, and i want it to change to another one when the mouse passes by.
It seems correct to me, but it always appear big, in its normal size (128px x 128px), and BEHIND the another image. (the other one is inside a div with z-index:1), and the one with the mouseover img have z-index:999

here is my css

```
.class1{
    max-width:64px;
    max-height:64px;
}
.class1:hover{
    background-image:url(http://img195.imageshack.us/MOUSEOVER_IMAGE.png);
    width:64px;
    height:64px;
    z-index:999;
    background-position:top center;
```

and here is my image

```
<a href="http://mylink"><img class=class1 src="http://imageshack.us/NORMAL_IMAGE.png" alt="some text here" /></a>
```

Comment: A background image will always be in the background. Any elements in this element will be over the background, so what you're trying to accomplish with css will not work. What you could do is using javascript to change the `src` of the `img` tag.

Comment: what if i remove src from the img tag, and add background-image:url with the normal img to class1?

Comment: No, that will not work. You could remove the `img` tag and make it a div to set the `background-image` in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple issues going on here. Like Tobas mentioned, you're using a background image on the link, but you still have an image child element. z-index will not bring a parent element's background above a child element.

So you have a couple options:

1: Change the img opacity to 0 on hover:

```
img.class1:hover { opacity: 0 }
```

And use background-size on the background image:

```
a:hover {
  background: url(...);
  background-size: 64px 64px;
 }
```

2: Remove the child image entirely, and have the images be swapped out as backgrounds to the link. This makes sense if the image presents no semantic value.

```
a { background: url(image1.png); }

 a:hover { background: url(image2.png); }
```

3: Swap the *image itself* with javascript/jquery:

```
 $('img.class1').hover(function(){
    $(this).attr('src','image2.png');
 }
```

Comment: The first option worked, but .class1:hover img seems to be ignored by the browser.

Comment: Ok, i still haven't found a way to make .class1:hover img{ opacity: 0 } to work

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the background of the image. Unless you are changing its opacity to 0 you won't see the background.

I suggest to remove the image and give the a-tag your class. In addition specify the image-src as normal background.

```
.class1{
display:block;
background-image:url(...);
...}
.class:hover{...}
```

and your link `<a href="http://mylink" class="class1">&nbsp;</a>`

Comment: Giving the a-tag the class1 class, make it 128px x 128px

Answer (score 0):

don't forget to add the properties below (to the class/tag/div containing the `background-image` property). Otherwise, it will repeat in some cases:

```
{
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat
}
```